# Subtracting value from previous row sql by group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following dataset:

```
DATA_FIM    CENTRO  C   M   ESTOQUE
2018-02-01  HD01    CD  70  539.000
2018-03-01  HD01    CD  70  511.000
2018-04-01  HD01    CD  70  468.000
2018-05-01  HD01    CD  70  447.000
2018-06-01  HD01    CD  70  382.000
2018-07-01  HD01    CD  70  348.000
2018-08-01  HD01    CD  70  285.000
2018-09-01  HD01    CD  70  245.000
2018-10-01  HD01    CD  70  221.000
2018-11-01  HD01    CD  70  207.000
2018-12-01  HD01    CD  70  122.000
2018-12-21  HD01    CD  70  101.000
2018-02-01  HD01    CD  71  164.000
2018-03-01  HD01    CD  71  147.000
2018-04-01  HD01    CD  71  124.000
2018-05-01  HD01    CD  71  107.000
2018-06-01  HD01    CD  71  78.000
```

1- Considering the 2nd, 3rd, 4th columns as a group, I want to subtract the 5th column values from previous row of same column.

In order to create a new row.

[![Data][2]][2]

It's very similar with this problem: [Issue:13196190][3], however, in my case I have multiple index, and I am not sure how to solve.

## UPDATED

I am using the suggested codes

```
select 
ZBI_FAT_PRODUCT.DATA_FIM,
        ZBI_DIM_EMPRESA.CENTRO, 
        ZBI_DIM_EMPRESA.CANAL, 
        ZBI_DIM_PRODUCT.MATERIAL, 
        ZBI_DIM_PRODUCT.TITULO,
        ZBI_FAT_PRODUCT.ESTOQUE_VENDA, 
        LAG(ZBI_FAT_PRODUCT.ESTOQUE_VENDA, 1, ZBI_FAT_PRODUCT.ESTOQUE_VENDA) OVER (PARTITION BY ZBI_DIM_EMPRESA.CENTRO, ZBI_DIM_PRODUCT.MATERIAL, ZBI_DIM_PRODUCT.TITULO ORDER BY ZBI_FAT_PRODUCT.DATA_FIM) - ZBI_FAT_PRODUCT.ESTOQUE_VENDA AS NEW
FROM ZBI_DIM_EMPRESA INNER JOIN (ZBI_DIM_PRODUCT INNER JOIN ZBI_FAT_PRODUCT ON ZBI_DIM_PRODUCT.BK = ZBI_FAT_PRODUCT.BK_MATERIAL) ON ZBI_DIM_EMPRESA.BK = ZBI_FAT_PRODUCT.BK_EMPRESA;
```

Comment: "I want to subtract the 5th column values from previous row" - from the same column of the prevoius row? And for the 3rd row, do you want to subtract it from the raw value of the 2nd row, or from the reduced value?

Comment: OK, I see, you always want the difference, except the first row, where it is 0.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Have you tried using LAG window function? It's available from version 2012+ only but it fits here like a glove.

Comment: @ Cesar I deleted my answer because on review, Gordons answer is the correct one. You dont actually need `COALESCE`, this will work with just the lag function as such: `LAG(ZBI_FAT_PRODUCT.ESTOQUE_VENDA, 1,  ZBI_FAT_PRODUCT.ESTOQUE_VENDA) OVER (PARTITION BY ZBI_DIM_EMPRESA.CENTRO, ZBI_DIM_PRODUCT.MATERIAL, ZBI_DIM_PRODUCT.TITULO ORDER BY ZBI_FAT_PRODUCT.DATA_FIM) - ZBI_FAT_PRODUCT.ESTOQUE_VENDA AS NEW`

Comment: Thank you very much @BarryPiccinni

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to just want `lag()`:

```
select el.*,
       (lag(estoque, 0, estoque) over (partition by centro, c, m order by date_mif) -
        estoque
       ) as diff
from energylog el;
```

EDIT:

For the edited question, only two columns seem to comprise a group

```
select el.*,
       (lag(estoque, 0, value) over (partition by centro, canal, order by date_mif) -
        estoque
       ) as diff
from energylog el;
```

Comment: `LAG` is the the solution, but probably `COALESCE(LAG(ESTOQUE) OVER (PARTITION BY CENTRO, C, M ORDER BY DATA_FIM) - ESTOQUE, 0) AS [New]` is more appropriate here. +1. Thanks.

Comment: I am trying to use both suggested methods, however, most of the rows from 'estoque' and '[New]' appears a 0 value. (before it was not true).

Comment: @Zhorov . . . The `coalesce()` is not necessary in this case; the default argument to `lag()` handles the first row in each group.

Comment: @Cesar . . . Your sample data and the data in your edit are different.  You seem to want to define the groups by only two columns, not three.

Comment: What should I use on inside lag function ? When I keep the 'Value' Argument, it returns Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Invalid column name 'value'.

Comment: I updated the code again, see above. It only works without 'Value' argument

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, without `COALESCE` shoul be `LAG(ESTOQUE, 1, ESTOQUE) OVER (PARTITION BY CENTRO, C, M ORDER BY DATA_FIM) - ESTOQUE AS [New]`,

Answer (score 1):

For brevity, and to extract the solution from the comments -

The answer is to use the `LAG()` function:

```
SELECT *, 
LAG(ESTOQUE, 1, ESTOQUE) OVER (PARTITION BY CENTRO, C, M ORDER BY DATA_FIM) - ESTOQUE AS New
FROM EnergyLog
```

Here is an example of this working: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a531b/17)

Comment: Thank you very much @BarryPiccinni